# Cloudwatch get-metric-statistics are not accurate

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to get `get-metric-statistics` from Cloudwatch, but I found a little difference from what I have in Cloudwatch and what I receive from the following aws cli command:

> aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --metric-name EnqueueCount
>   --start-time 2018-08-13T10:15:00Z --end-time 2018-08-13T10:16:01Z --period 60 --namespace AWS/AmazonMQ --statistics SampleCount --dimensions Name=Broker,Value=BrokerNameName=Queue,Value=QueueName

For the same period of time in Cloudwatch I have different EnqueueCount, but from aws cli command I receive the same value all over again.

Does anyone know why is that?

Answer (score 0):

AWS get-metric-statistics considers end-time as exclusive and start-time as inclusive. 
In you case, to get the right count set start-time to 2018-08-13T10:15:00Z and end-time to 2018-08-13T10:17:00Z with period of 60s.
 For further reading
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-metric-statistics.html